# Qgis 1.9 commitChanges() and Redraw a temporary layer

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

Using QGIS 1.9 and writing a python plugin.  I have a function that connects points into polylines and draws them as a temporary, in memory layer.  Membership in a polyline is determined by a field in the attribute table (postgis enabled table) of the point.

The tool programatically sets up an edit session and alters the correct column in the point attribute table to alter the polylineID.

pseudocode:

```
layer.startEditing()

...Make edits to the features (not a data provider)...

layer.commitChanges()
remove in-memory layer
redraw in-memory layer by iterating over the point table to building polylines
```

The redraw fails to see the edits that have occurred.  This is after calling `layer.commitChanges()`.  What is the proper method to make an edit and propagate it so that an immediately derived layer sees the changes?

Tested with data in geojson on disk and via a view on a postgis table.

Comment: "derived layer" in what sense?

Comment: Derived in that it is generated from the layer that is being edited.

Comment: How did you generate it?  Unless the layer is coming from the same dataset there is no relation.

Comment: Ahhh I see you are creating a in memory layer.  There isn't going to be a connection between that and the main dataset.

Comment: The 'source' dataset is a postgis table.  This is what is edited.  On load, I use it to derive my in memory layer.  I then edit the source, remove the in memory layer, and then rebuild the in memory layer.  On rebuild, I am not able to capture the edits to the source, even if I commit them.  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: If you commit them you should be able to get them using the normal means

Comment: Are they showing up in pgAdmin?

Comment: Got it.  This fails on a view, but propagates on a table.  Also not sure why geojson write was failing.  I'll investigate.  Not sure if this is of value to write up to help someone else or too specific.  Thanks for the info / questions.

Comment: GeoJson is read only and write only, not read+write